# How to make a close button "X" stand out from a image

Tags: buttons, css, close, overlay

I have an image looks like satellite map where I want to put a close button at the top right corner. 
What I have now is just a span with "X".

It's an 100% overlay on a popup so clicking outside would close the popup where I only want to close the overlay.

But because the image itself can have any color, thus no matter what color I make the "X" to be, it's not always very visible to the user.

Is there any (CSS) tricks that can make the close button stand out?
I've heard about box-shadow but not sure how it can help in this case.

Having a dedicated header to just hold the close button feels feels too much.

Comment: How about a semitransparent border of 3 to 5 pixels, and a semitransparent square with rounded corners in one corner of it?

Comment: Instead of a dedicated header you could always have the X itself overhang to be more prominent like this: https://www.drupal.org/files/chrome_8.png

Comment: @DasBeasto Since the image overlay would take 100% of the original popup, it would be awkward to have something hanging outside of the popup only when the overly is opened

Comment: @jackiemb Sorry I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. Can I have some img or css snippet?

Comment: @LoveProgramming Oh I see what you mean I misread the original, you're correct that would be awkward. 

Also I assume jackie means something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1fo6rzk8/

Comment: I should know better than to say in words what a picture will demonstrate.

Comment: This seems like a confusing way of doing things for the user. You appear to have guessed their instincts in clicking outside the popup to close it but the chances of them doing that to close any subsequent overlays is extremely high and will be extremely frustrating for them - I suggest you look at your architecture and see if you can find another way to deliver the map rather than as an overlay on a popup.

Comment: @AndrewMartinYes you are right, I don't quite like this idea of a non-loading overlay on top of a popup either. Unfortunately, I don't own the whole project, and this are the specification I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

The border gives the overlay coherence of design. Putting the X on a background like the circular one here means that it will always show up. If you make it semitransparent then you maximise the amount you can see underneath, if what's underneath is important.

Comment: +1 exactly. The white background will contrast dark colors and the black X will contrast light colors so no matter what it is overlaying it will always be seen.

Comment: This lookd great! Would it look good without the semi-transparent border around the image? Since there is a potential side panel at the left side of the image..

Comment: Glad to be of service. It would still look ok without the border but it would look less 'designed'. The border helps the eye to separate back and foreground. In conjunction with the x background it draws the eye around the image and toward the x

Answer (score 0):

One standard trick photographers use for watermarks is to take the image of the watermark and invert the colour, shift down and to the side by a couple of pixels and then combine so if you put an X on a transparent, or translucent, but bordered box and perform the same trick it will show on any background.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Maps' inspiration: have a colored background and a white X. And once the users mouse hover over it, it shows some shadow.

[image]

[image]